# What would be the equivalent syntax of require(package1)(<package1's dependency>) for es6's import?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have searched enough and skimmed through the documentation of import available on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import

I still didn't get an answer as to what would be the syntax for:

```
import React from 'react';
var InfiniteScroll = require('react-infinite-scroll')(React);
```

I am not sure how to write **require('react-infinite-scroll')(React)** using **import**.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: You are probably looking for something like this:

    import React from 'react';
    import InfiniteScrollCosntructor from 'react-infinite-scroll';
    const infiniteScroll = InfiniteScrollCosntructor(React);

Comment: There's nothing special about it, it's just running a function with argument `React`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import InfiniteScrollCosntructor from 'react-infinite-scroll'; 
const infiniteScroll = InfiniteScrollCosntructor(React);
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. That worked.